# Popup 'close' button doesn't work on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, mobile

I'm not sure why but the popup (which only shows once per session) has a close button (X) which doesn't work on an iPhone. However, it works fine on desktop. Below is the code I am using. Is there anything I can do to make this work?

Here is the [site](http://daxdesign.com).

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown'){
    $("#popup-wrap").delay(2000).fadeIn();
    sessionStorage.setItem('popState','shown')
}

$('body').on('click touch', '#popup-close', function() {
    $('#popup-wrap').fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, iPhone has trouble with the jQuery.on event.
Try binding a function to the pop-up element eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closePopup() {
        $('#popup-wrap').fadeOut();
    }
</script>

<div id="popup-wrap">
    <span onclick="closePopup()">X</span>
</div>
```